# Cannot create a new project with ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

I've seen this problem on stack overflow few days ago, and the next day I have it too.

I am unable to create a new ionic project with cordova.

[image]

When the prompt ask me if I want to integrate cordova with the app and whatever my answer was (Yes or no), I have to wait hours and hours and nothing happens and just a folder with just single file (src) is created.

I am using the latest version of Node and NPM.

I tried to uninstall everything globally and re-install it again, but still having the same problem.

Any help would be appreciated. I can't provide any more details as this is what I got. I tried everything from removing/uninstalling all and then re-install. Restart computer, even change it. The internet speed is good (I don't think it has something to do with it).

**Update**

I tried to add `--no-git` to the command and still doing the same thing:

`ionic start proj tabs --no-git`

Answer (score 0):

Try with a `--no-git`. At least this helped this guy: [github issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/2361)

Comment: Nope. Still doing the same thing.

Comment: Then try `--no-cordova` and install this manuall with `cd proj && npm install cordova`

Comment: Nope. Can i download a raw version of IONIC ?